# Show the rational representation of e "converges to e" under constructive math, i.e. show that $\sum _{k=j+1}^i \frac{1}{k!} \le \frac{1}{n}$.

Tags: summation, constructive-mathematics

I'm trying to show that $e$ has a representation in constructive mathematics from Wikipedia's definition of convergence and definition of finite e.

Here is their definition of "convergence": letting $f$ be a function that takes a positive integer $n$ and outputs a rational $f(n)$, together with a function $g$ such that g takes a positive integer and outputs a positive integer $g(n)$ such that:

[image: Wikipedia]

Basically instead of $\epsilon$, they squeeze rational numbers outputted by $f$ together with $1/n$. (It's a very nice trick, in my limited opinion.)

According to Wiki, $e$ has representation given a function f such that $f(n) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{i!}$, $g(n) = n$.

I tried to verify that the rational approximation of $e$ given by $f$ and $g$ really does "converge". To do this, I needed to show the above definition holds for the representation given by $f,g$ as below:

[image: f,g]

Since the definition of "convergence" was given in terms of $n, i, j$, I restated

$f(i) = \sum_{k=0}^i \frac{1}{k!}$, $f(j) = \sum_{k=0}^j \frac{1}{k!}$

This gave me a very natural bound, i.e. for $i \gt j \geq n \geq 1$,

$|f(i) - f(j)|$ = $\sum_{k=j+1}^i \frac{1}{k!}$ which in turn I have no idea how to bound it by $1/n$.

($i = j$ gives me my result instantly, since $|f(i) - f(j)| = 0 \leq \frac{1}{n}, \forall n \geq 1$ so we assume $i \gt j$ WLOG)

I tried some sum formulas, strong induction, directly manipulating the series, basically everything under the sun but I could not show this.

I feel like it should be easy but I have no clue why I can't get it. Any small hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The usual approaches to establish the convergence of this sum have no non-constructive steps.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite close.

You have $|f(i)-f(j)| = \displaystyle\sum_{k = j+1}^i \dfrac{1}{k!}$. You want to bound that by $1/n$ for some $n$ (actually, note that in the definition of convergence that you stated, the point is to bound $|f(i)-f(j)|$ by a **decreasing function that converges to 0** (which is enough to show that the distance between two points will converge to $0$, which in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (a complete space) is the same thing as convergence. So here, you are trying to bound your left-hand-side by $1/n$, but you could use other functions like $1/n^2, 1/n!$, etc... or anything that converges to $0$).

So now let's look at it. Clearly, $(k+1)! > k! \implies \dfrac{1}{(k+1)!} < \dfrac{1}{k!}$.

Therefore, $\displaystyle\sum_{k = j+1}^i \dfrac{1}{k!} = \dfrac{1}{k!} + \dfrac{1}{(k+1)!} + ... + \dfrac{1}{i!} < \dfrac{1}{k!} + \dfrac{1}{k!} + ... + \dfrac{1}{k!} = \dfrac{i-k}{k!}$

Now, you are almost done, because the right hand side converges to $0$ as $k \to \infty$. Indeed, the top of the fraction keeps growing as $i \to \infty$, but it grows very slowly, whereas the bottom is a factorial, so it will "beat" the top and force the fraction to go to $0$.

Now, proceeding from there, your goal is to find a number $n$ such that, for $i,k \geq n$, you have $\dfrac{i-k}{k!} \leq 1/n$.
I'll leave you to do this, let me know if you want me to add some stuff to my answer :)

*Note: there are many other ways this could have been done. Since it doesn't really matter what we bound $|f(i)-f(j)|$, as long as it converges to $0$, often we end up making "crude" bruteforce approximations in the calculations. So don't be scared about approximating things in your answer: as long as you keep in mind what you are trying to bound, and don't lose any information in the process!*

An example of one of those crude approximations, for example, is that in the bound by $\dfrac{i-k}{k!}$, we can replace that fraction by $\dfrac{i}{k!}$. It looks like we are losing some information, but actually not really, because $|f(i)-f(j)| < \dfrac{k-i}{k!} < \dfrac{i}{k!}$. So if we manage to bound above the rightmost term, we can definitely bound the leftmost one.

Comment: Why do we have control over n? I thought i, j, and n are given to you.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I missed that detail. The truth it: it doesn't really matter that $n$ is given. The main idea of the proof is to show that the Taylor series for the exponential is \textbf{Cauchy}, meaning that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $n$ such that for $i,j \geq n$, $|f(i)-f(j)| < \varepsilon$. That is enough to prove convergence. It looks like, instead of doing that, they decide to only consider the series of exp up until the $n$-th term. This makes no difference as, in the end, you're proving the same thing: that terms of the sequences get closer and closer to each other.

Comment: Isn't the whole point that you're not allowed to use $\epsilon > 0$ in your proof? It's supposed to be constructive right?

How would you bound i > j given, such that n is also given and i,j >=n s.t. i/(i-j)! <= 1/n.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "being constructive", to me all these proofs are constructive, and all of them are essentially the same. But maybe I'm missing a definition of "constructive". In any case, replacing $1/n$ by $\varepsilon > 0$ is absolutely possible and will not change the proof in any way, you would simply write $\forall i,j \geq n : |f(i)-f(j)| < \varepsilon$; and the reasoning will be exactly the same.

Comment: The reason they try to bound $|f(i)-f(j)|$ by $1/n$ is mostly because it's convenient, and given the function that we are working with, it is easier to find a bound of the form $1/n$ for some integer